# How to properly delete certain beats from a measure in Music21

Tags: python, music21, musicxml

I'm using Music21 to programmatically edit MusicXML files in my dataset. What I'm trying to do is divvy up audio and corresponding MusicXML into little snippets. This means that sometimes, snippets' start or end don't align perfectly with the beginning or end of a measure, so I need to delete a certain number of beats in the beginning or end measure.

I want to figure out if there's already a proper way, knowing which beats in a measure to delete, to do this using Music21.

Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
from music21 import *

musicxml = converter.parse(xml_file_path)
musicxml = musicxml.measures(1,3)
musicxml.show()
```

[image: output]

```
musicxml = musicxml.some_function_that_removes_first_few_beats(remove_beats=3)
musicxml.show()
```

[image: output]

Comment: What exactly should it mean to "delete" beats from the middle of the music? Should they be replaced with rests? Should everything past that point be shifted back (even if it completely messes up the rhythm)? Something else? Do you actually need to be able to delete from the middle, or only from the end?

Comment: Hey Karl: 1. I'd like to replace these beats with rests. 2. I don't wish to delete anything from the middle – rather, each of these snippets will be written to separate xml files, so in essence I only wish to edit the beginning and end of each musicxml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made separate functions for deleting beats at the start of the excerpt and deleting beats at the end of the excerpt:

```
def delete_first_beats(xml_score, start_measure, start_beat):
    xml_score = copy.deepcopy(xml_score)
    start_offset = start_beat - 1
    for measure in xml_score.recurse(classFilter=('Measure')):
        if measure.number == start_measure:
            removed = set()
            for note_or_rest in measure.recurse(classFilter=('Note', 'Rest')):
                if note_or_rest.offset < start_offset:
                    removed.add(note_or_rest.activeSite)
                    note_or_rest.activeSite.remove(note_or_rest)
            for stream in removed: stream.insert(0, note.Rest())
    return xml_score
```

And:

```
def delete_last_beats(xml_score, end_measure, end_beat):
    xml_score = copy.deepcopy(xml_score)
    end_offset = end_beat - 1
    for measure in xml_score.recurse(classFilter=('Measure')):
        if measure.number == end_measure:
            removed = set()
            for note_or_rest in measure.recurse(classFilter=('Note', 'Rest')):
                if note_or_rest.offset > end_offset:
                    removed.add(note_or_rest.activeSite)
                    note_or_rest.activeSite.remove(note_or_rest)
            for stream in removed: stream.insert(end_beat, note.Rest())
    return xml_score
```